# TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentTarget' of undefined

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, reactjs

```
    function Search(props)
    {
  return(
      <input type="text" value={ props.value } onChange={ () => props.onChanging() } />
    )
}
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      inputValue: "",
      loading: true,
      hits: null,
    }

    this.onDismiss = this.onDismiss.bind(this);
    this.onChanging = this.onChanging.bind(this);
  }


  onChanging(e)
  {
    console.log(e.currentTarget.value);
    console.log(this.state.inputValue);
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    const url = "https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search";
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({ hits: data.hits, loading: false });
  }


  onDismiss(id) {
    const isNotId = item => item.objectID !== id;
    const updatedHits = this.state.hits.filter(isNotId);

    this.setState({ hits: updatedHits});

    console.log(this.state.hits);
  }



  render() {

    return (
      

      <div className="container">
        {this.state.loading ?
          <div>loading...</div> :
          <div>hits:<br />
            <Search value={this.state.inputValue} onChanging={this.onChanging} />
            {this.state.hits.map((item) =>
              item.title === null ? '' :
              <div key={item.objectID}>
                {item.title} - <a target="_blank" href={item.url}> {item.url}</a>
                &nbsp;
                <button onClick={()=>this.onDismiss(item.objectID)}>RESET</button>
              </div>
            )}
            <div className="viewmore">View more story</div>
          </div>
          }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

как получить значение из инпута? в чем проблема

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хорошо бы передать туда какой-нибудь аргумент:

```
... () => props.onChanging() ...
```

Comment: понял, спасибо:)*

Comment: @Istinnavvine Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.